# Is there going to be a .net 5?

Tags: .net

I've been trying to find out when .NET 5 is going to come out, or if there is no current plan for it. Does anyone have any ideas? I've looked on wikipedia and various Microsoft blogs, as well as Google...
Thanks

Comment: No 4.5 ought to be enough for everybody ;)

Comment: If it's coming out soon, it'll likely be in the [VS2014 CTP](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs.aspx). I don't have that installed but at first glance it doesn't look like it has a new version: [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/03/announcing-web-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx) still says 4.5. Otherwise the next likely place will be Windows 9, if that's not meant to coincide with VS2014. Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's current roadmap includes up to 4.5.2 (released May 2014) right now. There are no announcements for .Net 5.0 that I could find (and I would love to be proven wrong).

```
Version history:

.Net 1.0: February 2002
.Net 1.1: April 2003
.Net 2.0: January 2006   --   Release coincided with VS2005
.Net 3.0: Novenber 2006   --   Release coincided with Vista
.Net 3.5: November 2007
.Net 3.5 SP1: August 2008
.Net 4: May 2009   --   Release coincided with Windows 7
.Net 4.5: August 20012   --   Release coincided with Windows 8
.Net 4.5.1: October 2013   --   Release coincided with VS2013
.Net 4.5.2: May 2014
```

As you can see, major (or half major, sometimes) release cycles frequently associated with a new Windows release or Visual Studio release.It stands to reason that .Net 5 would theoretically come out of the closet when Windows Threshold is released.

Answer (score 2):

Right now it seems like they are focused on improving their tooling support for 4.5 with [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20feature%20status&referringTitle=Home) and yearly/quarterly iterations and improvements to visual studio. There is a new version of [c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) and vb.net coming down the pipe, but they will run under 4.5 framework.

I'm sure a version 5 will come out at some point, but it's probably going to be a while. There are no published plans at this point.